# how to add html in a email body using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html-email

I have to sent a confirmation email to the users.
and on clicking of a link, i want to open their default email client and add a HTML into the body tag.

```
var subject = Your transaction No: +': ' + $('#confirmationNumber').text()+ ' is confirmed';
var emailBody = $('#confirmation').html();
$(this).attr('href','mailto:'+userEmail+'&subject=' + subject +'&body='+ emailBody);
```

it want the HTML in 'emailBody' to get appended to the body as HTML. But it displays me the entire HTML tags instead.

**Is  there a way i can append a HTML in the body ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is short but unfortunate:

**No.**

When using `mailto:`-links, you can only specify text, not HTML.  Even if the user’s mail client composes a mail message using HTML, your body text will only be inserted as text.

There’s nothing you can do about that from a web page.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var emailBody = $('#confirmation').text();
```

Comment: yeh i used that... but it appends all the text in one line in the email body... I want some bold tags and line breaks in them.

Comment: Body must be 'text/plain', You cannot use HTML Tags in there.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, some fixes to your code:

```
var subject = 'Your transaction No: ' + $('#confirmationNumber').text() + ' is confirmed',
    emailBody = $('#confirmation').html();
$(this).attr('href', 'mailto:' + userEmail + '&subject=' + subject + '&body=' + encodeURI(emailBody));
```

- Use single `var` keyword and separate variables with commas
- `subject` was concatenated badly

Next, if you want to pass html code in link you have to encode special chars, which `encodeURI()` does.

---

Oops, encoded body isn't treated as html in email client..
I googled for a while and it seems you can't pass it correctly, can't you send a message instead of opening client?

Comment: 1stly sorry for the bad subject concatenaiton, i had typed that one. and :( for hte encodeURI. It was a client requirement. But ur right.. i will send it as a messge instead..